# Emulsifier for water, been oil

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am trying to blend neem oil and water and I'm wondering what the best emulsifier would be 10% neem oil 90% water thank you

Comment: been oil, neem oil ? now which of them? What is "blend", what properties should that emulsion have? What's it supposed to be good for? Also you say you are "trying". Now what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to do this. The easy way, and the right way.

Traditionally people will use dish soap. 
1 tsp neem oil to 1/2 tsp dish soap to 1 quart water
(https://www.greenhousemegastore.com/supplies/insect-prevention/pure-neem-oil)

Ten percent oil (actual oil, not oil phase) is actually pretty high. Just letting you know this in advance. You'll be making a greasy feeling lotion.

Without getting into emulsions (as I don't know what kind of access you have to more "advanced" cosmetic emulsifiers) too much, I'd say to simply melt 2.5% Emulsifying Wax NF (I like Polawax but NF means national formulary, means it's all standardized to be the same. Polawax is different from NF) with the 10% neem oil to $\pu{70 ^\circ C}$, bring 87.5% distilled water up to $\pu{70 ^\circ C}$ and pour oil into water while stirring fast (you can use handmixer, etc.).

If 2.5% emulsifying wax doesn't hold the neem oil for some reason, add a percent or two more wax and heat everything to $\pu{70 ^\circ C}$ again and mix.

For reference, neem oil has an HLB of 9. 
(http://www.saffireblue.ca/blog/required-hlb-of-oils-and-lipids.htm) 
You don't need to know this if you're going with emulsifying wax, but you will if you want another nonionic emulsifier. Explaining how to use the HLB system is beyond the scope of this answer.

Cheers